# Apache2 does not work, but syntax is OK

Tags: apache2, firewall

I installed `apache2`, but it doesn't work.
I also allowed it in `ufw`.
The output in terminal after

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

is "Syntax OK". I am using Ubuntu 16.04.
What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by do not work? Is the service not starting? Is the host not reachable over http?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a version of Ubuntu with a GUI, try entering `http://localhost` into the address bar of your web browser. This should show the default configuration page for Apache2. If it doesnt, then run `sudo systemctl apache2 start`, then try your browser again. If you don't have a GUI on the local machine, access it by entering `http://(server IP address)` into the address bar of another machine, but otherwise the process is the same.